# How to get the arguments or parameters of launch file in node file?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, roslaunch, parameter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm using ROS melodic of Ubuntu 18.04.

I'm trying to spawn 4 different robots and get their pose every time in the Gazebo simulation.

I had gotten `/odom` topic of each, but also noticed `/odom` topic is the relative from a local frame.

So I additionally need to get each robot's initial pose to convert from the local `/odom` to global `/odom`.

However, I practically set the initial pose in launch file, not Python node file.

If I can get those arguments or parameters (actually I'm not still familiar with the launch file so I'm not sure my word is right) in the Python node file, I think I can do many things wrt pose correction.

More specifically, I want to get arguments like

```
<arg name="init_pose" .......>
```

in the Python file.

So if anyone who is familiar with the launch file is here, would you please give me some advice?

Thanks in advance :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/346786/how-to-get-the-arguments-or-parameters-of-launch-file-in-node-file?/) by [kane_choigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45263/kane_choigo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2020-03-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you could use arg as described on this page to pass values to a node,[roslaunch](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML)
or param to put values on the parameter server and then read them from there in the node

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2020-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2